# How to clean up user event contained resource after channel closed

Tags: netty

I have some thread send user event message object (which contains a ByteBuf) to the channel, and then these message will be handled in userEventTriggered() handler method, which do some logic and finally write to channel, so that the ByteBuf contained in event message object then released by netty automatically. But I found if channel closed, the userEventTriggered() will not be called any more, so the ByteBuf is leaked in the internal user event message queue.

Currently, I use a ConcurrentLinkedQueue to store pending user event message object. If I want to send message to channel, I put the message to the queue, and notify channel by other message object. If channel is active, it will fetch message from queue, otherwise the message is retained in the queue, at the last, the messages remains in the queue will be cleanup in some process.

This solution seems works, but there may be more simple and graceful resolutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood this is the right way how to handle it. You may also want consider just not put messages in the queue for closed channels as netty itself will release user-events if these hit the end of the pipeline.

Comment: But in some rare case, the channel may closed just after channel.isActive() returne true.